# Verify url as a downloadable video - Python

Tags: python

Given a url, how can I verify that the url points to a **downloadable video**?

Given this scenario, what is the implementation of the function `is_downloadable_video(url)`:

```
downloadable_video_url = 'https://pixabay.com/en/videos/download/video-8579_large.mp4?attachment'
not_downloadable_url = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'

is_downloadable_video(downloadable_video_url)   # Returns True
is_downloadable_video(not_downloadable_url)   # Returns False
```

Comment: In the end, the most reliable way would probably be for you to attempt to download the video, characterize the result, then attempt to play it locally in a suitable application. If any step along the way causes an error, it's not a downloadable video. Checking a generic URL tells you nothing if you don't know what the server does with it.

Comment: And I think you don't even need to download the whole video. few seconds of video is enough, you will be able to play it if file is not corrupted.

Comment: Great solutions, please post an answer that implements any of these methods and I'll accept it :)

Comment: HTTP HEAD (instead of GET) wouldn't be fully reliable, but it may be "good enough" for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This checks for valid `html`:

```
import requests
urls = ['https://pixabay.com/en/videos/download/video-8579_large.mp4?attachment',
        'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.head(url)
    print "text/html" in r.headers["content-type"]
```

In my opinion, this checks if downloadable:

```
for url in urls:
    print 'download=1' in ''.join(requests.head(url).headers.values())
```

Comment: Looks neat, but can you explain why "text/html" assures it is a downloadable video?

Comment: Please see the edit. My opinion is that it checks if download is automatically started.

Comment: Seems great and actually works with the examples I've given, but I'm not fully familiar with the 'download' flag and the 'text/html' content-type meaning to accept the answer, I did upvote it anyway

Comment: Do you have more examples?

Comment: This is for production environment, I can't generate all the examples, next week I will try out some more urls I'll find and I'll update